# Spring Boot: How to change the value of an annotation based on profile?

Tags: spring-boot, redis, annotations, environment-variables, profile

We use redis as the data source. But we just have one redis server, so development and production environment have to share the server. So I wish to use different @RedisHash prefixes on objects based on their profile. I have 2 profiles, dev and prod.

For example, For Object Participant, I wish it to use `@RedisHash('redis.prod_Participant')` for production and `@RedisHash('redis.dev_Participant')` for development.

So I change `application-prod.yaml` file to

```
redis:
  host: 9.9.9.9
  port: 6379
  password: 1234
  participant_db_name: prod_Participant
```

But how can I set the value of @RedisHash based on profile? I have tried `@RedisHash(@Value("${redis.participant_db_name}"))` but the value of @RedisHash must be of String type instead of Value type and the compiler complains about incompatibility.

I also tried `@RedisHash("${redis.participant_db_name}")` but instead of using `prod_Participant`, the literal `${redis.participant_db_name}` is used instead.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you have multiple application.yml files based on profile?

Comment: did you set spring:
  profiles:
    active: prod

Comment: @K.D Yes, I have multiple application.yml based on profile

Comment: @ShaileshChandra Yes, I can set the profile to prod using command java -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -jar ./ROOT.jar.

Comment: can you see a comment like below when you start application
- **The following profiles are active: prod**
or **No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default**

Comment: @ShaileshChandra I can see The following profiles are active: prod. The problem I am trying to figure out is to let RedisHash annotation use the right value which I set to participant_db_name. Its value is different for each profile yaml.

Comment: I can suggest and interim fix until you find permanent solution

Comment: @ShaileshChandra It's ok, I just need to make sure if there is a solution, I am aware of it. If it is not supported yet, than I will think of other alternatives. :-)

Comment: I would have tried no other like you are doing, can you also try with @RedisHash("#{redis.participant_db_name}")

Comment: @ShaileshChandra This doesn't work either. This is the key's name inside redis: "#{redis.participant_db_name}"

Comment: I was again thinking why can't you use the same property name for prod and different value based on profile, also if you could share a dummy project on github